# css changes for dockbar liferay 6.2

Tags: css, css-float, liferay-theme

I am using liferay 6.2 using my custom theme and for dockbar I want to modify css. I have border and I want my dockbar height and width to be same as my border size so I have done some modification in custom.css as shown below

```css
.aui .dockbar-split .dockbar.navbar-static-top .collapse .nav-account-controls {
    left: 1259px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
```

please see the image below of dockbar in which red color is border and black color is dockbar and I need dockbar must be on top of border of same border height and width.

and I tried fixing by position:fixed and by providing padding-right in custom.css but this would be fixed for temprory and the dockbar keeps moving for different resolution of screen

[Please click here for dockbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXUIF.jpg)

Comment: You're trying to get "admin", "my sites", "user" in one row?

Comment: yes and it shouldn't move from that position though display screen size alters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by setting the width on .nav-account-controls, so please remove the width. You shouldn't set a width on this list since the name of the user is variable.